# Weinberg angle in terms of the Higgs mass

Tags: standard-model

The Weinberg angle $\Theta_{W}$ is commonly expressed as

$$\cos\Theta_{W} = M_{W}/M_{Z}.$$

---

Can the Weinberg angle $\Theta_{W}$ be expressed in terms of the Higgs mass and the mass of the W boson as

$$\sin^{2}\Theta_{W}= m_{H}/M_{W}?$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. The squared sine is much smaller than one while the Higgs-to-W mass ratio is larger than one. Why should one believe such a relationship?

No relationship like that may be true because up to late 2011 or officially July 2012, the Higgs mass was unknown. While the Z-boson and W-boson mass only depend on the Higgs vev $v$ and the electroweak couplings $g,g'$, the Higgs mass $m_H$ is also an increasing function of the Higgs quartic coupling $\lambda$. The variable $m_H$ is the only one in the expression that depends on this fundamental parameter in your equation which is why the equation cannot be true.